# Weird null at beginning of array

Tags: java, null

```
public String getValues(int start, int end) 
{
    String[] values  = new String[end+1];
    for(int i=start;i<values.length;i++)
    {
       if(i % ham != 0 && i % spam != 0)
       {
           values[i]=Integer.toString(i);
       }
       else if(i % ham == 0 && i % spam != 0)
       {
           values[i]= word2;
       }
       else if(i % ham != 0 && i % spam == 0)
       {
           values[i]= word3;
       }
       else if(i % ham == 0 && i % spam == 0)
       {
           values[i]= word1;
       }
    }
    String str1= java.util.Arrays.toString(values);
    return str1;
}
```

Basically, you enter a ham value, spam value, a start, and an end. The method is supposed to run through the array and check if i is divisible by the ham number or spam number or both. If it isn't, it gives that element of the string Integer.toString(i);

Given `ham=3, spam=4, start=2, end=6`. It should produce `{2, ham, spam, 5, ham}`.

Mine produces `{null, null, 2, ham, spam, 5, ham}`. I have no idea where the first two nulls are coming from.

Comment: Please no code, don't want to plagiarize. Just would like some logical explanation of the two nulls and potential ways to get rid of them

Answer (score 1):

values has elements with indices 0 through end; since start=2, you never set any element with an index less than 2, so the elements at those indices retail their default values: null.

Comment: when I start the array at 0, it changes the first null to hamspam, and the second to 1. However, I need the array to start counting at 2, any way to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

The Arrays.toString prints the entire array, not just the part your method filled after the start index.  You said start=2, so the two positions before that would be null.

Comment: when I start the array at 0, it changes the first null to hamspam, and the second to 1. However, I need the array to start counting at 2, any way to make that happen?

Comment: Well, you could have all your if conditions work in terms of i+2, or you could use Arrays.copyOfRange to get only the elements you want, or you could write Arrays.toString yourself to respect your index bounds.

Comment: Tried doing Arrays.copyOfRange(values,2,end-1), but get the error incompatible types: no instance of type variable T exist so that T[] conforms to java.lang.String?

Comment: Did you try to assign it to a String? That'll give you another array, not a String, and you'd need to pass that to Arrays.toString.

Comment: Yeah I tried passing it to a string, makes sense why it didn't work. So basically the copyOfRange returns a new array based on the specified bounds then I have to assign that new array to a string with the toString(). Thank you for your help, and not giving me code. Really appreciate it man!